# Opening PDF from application on Safari

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios4

I am trying to open a PDF file in my app Bundle on Safari. I can open this PDF with applications like iBooks or other PDF readers. However I cant get it to open it with safari. Is there any way in which i can achieve this? I tried OpenURL but that doesnt work???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't open that in Safari since iOS apps are sandboxed. The solution available now would be to open the PDF using UIWebView or send it to another app that can handle PDF files.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you open in uiwebview?

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 200)];

NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/UIWebView_Class.pdf"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];

[self.view addSubview:webView];
[webView release];
```

Comment: I did do that but webview doesn't let you print it or enable any other functionality that safari can handle?

Comment: If you want to print the PDF document, then you could also try using UIDocumentInteractionController: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html